# How to display the text inside the button element from a different page at current page?

Tags: javascript, html

We have 2 webpages one.html & two.html.
In one.html we have a button element with text,

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

We want to display the content inside the button from one.html, i.e "Next" in two.html inside a

```
<p id="getfromone"></p>
```

We tried using jQuery about it, written below, called by a onload function with in body element.

```
document.getElementById("getfromone").innerHTML = $('#getfromone').load("one.html #next");
```

However, this only displays `[object Object]`

Please suggest what can be done about it.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and you won't get `[object][object]` any more

Comment: would it be like, $('#getfromone', JSON.stringify)? Not quite sure, where should I add it?

Comment: no it would be `JSON.stringify($('#getfromone').load("one.html #next"))`. But i'm not sure the you're using `load()` the correct way so i'm not sure about the outcome. `Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.` you need to have matched elements. so you need to have a `#next` in page two

Comment: show this now, {"0":{},"length":1}

Comment: Instead of this `document.getElementById("getfromone").innerHTML = $('#getfromone').load("one.html #next");` write this `$('#getfromone').load("one.html #next");` remove the assignment to innerHTML

Comment: Na, nothing's been displayed.

Comment: add a new div in two.html. add these lines $('#newDiv').load("one.html"); $('#newDiv #next').val() - you will get the button value.

Comment: @Prashanth, it's still not showing anything!! It seems like the binding of next with getfromone is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, You can check the working code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/prashanth-kuppanan/project/editor/AmOVPn).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var content;
      $("#oneDiv").load("one.html button#next", function(){
        content = $(this).text();
        $("#getfromone").text(content);
      });
});
```

Comment: The instructions, which you have shown on codepen, I tried that. It seems like working on chrome, but not in IE 11. Is there any specific reason for it, or it's just IE doesn't have jQuery compatibility? Is there any way we can run the code in IE as we're targeting that browser only.

Comment: You mean the codepen link is not working on IE11. Jquery has supports from IE 9+ . Please check in your IE 11 settings whether it is blocking jquery?

Comment: Solution working fine. Thanks for your time to help.